# How do I get thymeleaf to work in the .html files I use in my <iframe>?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I use the thymeleaf templating engine in my html code. My problem is that th works in the index.html iframe, but it doesn't work in other files that are used in the iframe.

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link th:href="@{style_main.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script th:src="@{jsc/welcomeRandom.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{jsc/searchSys.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{jsc/btnsLogic.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{jsc/iframeUpdater.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{js/code.jquery.com_jquery-3.7.0.min.js}"></script>
</head>
<body class="mainBody">

        <div class="ssss">
            <p>ты че еблан?</p>
            <img th:src="@{icons/sss.jpg}" alt="eblan">
        </div>

        <div class="welcome" id="welcomeRandom">
        </div>

    <div class="app">

        <div class="sidebarFull" id="sidebar">
            <div class="logo" onclick="changeIframe('categories/home.html')">
                <img th:src="@{svg/logo.svg}" alt="logo">
                <p th:text="${test}"></p>
            </div>

            <div class="categories">
                <a tabindex="0" class="categoriesBtn" onclick="changeIframe('categories/minecraft.html')"><img th:src="@{icons/minecraft.png}" alt="icon">Minecraft</a>
                <a tabindex="0" class="categoriesBtn" onclick="changeIframe('categories/terraria.html')"><img th:src="@{icons/terraria.png}" alt="icon">Terraria</a>
                <a tabindex="0" class="categoriesBtn" onclick="changeIframe('categories/other.html')"><img th:src="@{icons/other.png}" alt="icon">Прочее</a>
            </div>

            <div class="addBtnDiv">
                <a tabindex="0" class="addBtn" onclick="changeIframe('categories/submission_page.html')">Добавить</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="articleFull">
            <div class="articleTrue">
                <div class="searchBarDiv">
                    <label for="searchInput"></label>
                    <input class="searchBar" id="searchInput" placeholder="Поиск по названию">
                </div>
                <div class="iframeContainer">
                    <iframe th:src="@{categories/minecraft.html}" class="iframeTrueContainer" id="iframeTrueContainerId"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**minecraft.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>minecraft</title>
    <link href="../style_main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="../jsc/gridItemChecker.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="homeDiv">

    </div>
    <div class="gridContent">
        <div class="gridItem" th:each="file : ${files}">
            <div><img src="@{file.iconpath}" alt="icon"></div>
            <div class="packNameDiv"><p class="packName" th:text="${file.name}"></p></div>
            <div><p class="sizeName">Размер</p><p class="sizeFact" th:text="${file.filesize}"></p></div>
            <div><p class="option1">FML</p><p class="option2" th:text="${file.option1}"></p></div>
            <div><p class="option1">Версия</p><p class="option2" th:text="${file.option2}"></p></div>
            <a class="gridItemBtn" href="#" tabindex="0">Скачать</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**file system:**

[project file system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BA6e.png)

I want the thymeleaf tags to work in the other .html files that are used in my iframes, but instead they don't work and just stay in the html code of the page instead of replacing themselves with the required html code.

**1 EDIT:**

```
<div class="iframeContainer">
                    <iframe th:src="/categories/minecraft" class="iframeTrueContainer" id="iframeTrueContainerId"></iframe>
</div>
```

**MainController.java:**

```
@Controller
public class MainController {
    UsersFilesController controller;

    @Autowired
    public MainController(UsersFilesController controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(Model model){
        List<UsersFile> files = controller.getAll();
        model.addAttribute("files", files);
        System.out.println(model.getAttribute("files"));
        return "/main/index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/categories/minecraft")
    public String minecraft(Model model){
        return "categories/minecraft";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Thymeleaf` templates should reside in the `src/main/resources/templates` folder to be found with the default settings. You can even put them in a subfolder like `src/main/resources/templates/categories`.

If it is not OK for your project you can change the default settings in the `application.properties` like this:

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/whatever/
```

The correct syntax for `th:src` in `iframe` will be:

```
<iframe th:src="@{/categories/minecraft}"/>
```

where `/categories/minecraft` is the name of the endpoint in the controller class. This is the Java class annotated with `@Controller`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! But please tell me, if now the categories folder is in src/main/resources/templates( [photo](https://imgur.com/a/0ZG8JuN) ), how can I access it, for example, in this line: <iframe th:src="" class="iframeTrueContainer" id="iframeTrueContainerId"></iframe> ? What should I write in the th:src tag?

Comment: You should put there the endpoint from your web controller class. This is the Java class annotated with @Controller.

Comment: So in the end the line will look something like this? 
<iframe th:src="categories/minecraft" class="iframeTrueContainer" id="iframeTrueContainerId"></iframe>

Comment: Yes if `/categories/minecraft` is the endpoint defined like this `@GetMapping("/categories/minecraft")`. Please note: this endpoint should return `"categories/minecraft"` to show the template `categories/minecraft.html`

Comment: Sorry, but why I did everything as you said, but in the end I get an exception - org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "/categories/minecraft" (template: "/main/index" - line 49, col 29)

I have provided in the updated question text all the necessary information, could you please see what I did wrong?

Comment: I didn't check your comment. The correct syntax will be: `th:src="@{/categories/minecraft}"`

Comment: Thanks for the help, now I have everything working!